# How to check if a number appears in a column only one?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a numeric column in a data frame and I want to print all the numbers that appear only once. Such as:

```
Column
0
0
1
1
2
```

and my expected result should be:

```
2
```

and I am using this solution:

```
df[df['Column'].isin(df['Column'].value_counts([df['Column'].value_counts()==1].index)]
```

but it returns me an empty data frame and I am almost sure there are numbers that counts are only 1. Am I using the right solution?

Comment: Use `df = df.drop_duplicates('Column', keep=False)`

Comment: there are some numbers appearing 3,5,7 times

Comment: So need drop by number of values?

Comment: number of times it shows in the df column, but actually just tried your solution and I am getting an empty data frame back still, so maybe there really aren't single numbers

Comment: Not understand, solution not working? Can you explain more?

Comment: I think yo ucan sort values like `df = df.sort_values('Column')` and check if not all values are duplicated.

Comment: it's working! but I believe my dataframe just doesnt have unique values so that's why it's returning an empty one. Thank you!